# Организация динамической конфигурации системы

Tags: php, configuration

Конфиг храню как `php` классы

```
class NotificationModuleConfiguration
{
    public static $logsEnabled                          = 3;
    public static $serviceLogPrefix                     = "VM";
    public static $moduleLogPrefix                      = "NotificationModule";

    public static $kannelSendSmsUrl                     = "http://127.0.0.1:13101/cgi-bin/sendsms";

    public static $kannelUsername                       = "XXXX";
    public static $kannelPassword                       = "XXXX";
    public static $kannelPriority                       = 1;
    public static $kannelCharset                        = "UTF-8";
    public static $kannelDlrMask                        = 31;
}
```

Так же будет веб интерфейс, в котором можно будет менять настройки конфигурации.

Какой подход можно применить, чтобы получить из базы или из `Redis` к примеру новые настройки которые были внесены в веб интерфейсу, и переназначить значения свойствам в моем классе конфигурации.

**UPDATE:**
В Redis буду хранить наврное как HASH

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetAll NotificationModuleConfiguration
 1) "logsEnabled"
 2) "3"
 3) "serviceLogPrefix"
 4) "VM"
 5) "moduleLogPrefix"
 6) "NotificationModule"
 7) "kannelSendSmsUrl"
 8) "http://127.0.0.1:13101/cgi-bin/sendsms"
 9) "kannelUsername"
10) "XXXX"
11) "kannelPassword"
12) "XXXX"
13) "kannelPriority"
14) "1"
15) "kannelCharset"
16) "UTF-8"
17) "kannelDlrMask"
18) "31"
```

Или в более читабельном виде:

```
Array
(
    [logsEnabled] => 3
    [serviceLogPrefix] => VM
    [moduleLogPrefix] => NotificationModule
    [kannelSendSmsUrl] => http://127.0.0.1:13101/cgi-bin/sendsms
    [kannelUsername] => XXXX
    [kannelPassword] => XXXX
    [kannelPriority] => 1
    [kannelCharset] => UTF-8
    [kannelDlrMask] => 31
)
```

Comment: В каком виде приходят новые настройки из бызы или Redis которые были внесены в веб интерфейсу?

Comment: Дополнил в вопросе